# TestFlight: Is it possible to localize the TestFlight invitation email?

Tags: testflight

As I prepare to send out Testflight invitations to users, I was wondering if there is a way that I can send the invite email in Mandarin, instead of English? My test users are in China and I don't want to send them the usual invitation that goes out in English but want it to be in Mandarin. Does TestFlight show the text based on the native language in the iPad or iPhone? I tried changing my language to Mandarin on my iPhone but it did not change the language in the invitation. Your help in helping me see what I am missing here is very much appreciated.

Thanks,
Ajay